# Analyzing security of Django template code

Tags: django, security, nginx

I need help with some concepts.

In my Django web app, users write content and other users upvote/downvote the said content. Standard stuff.

The voting **used to** happen via POST. E.g. something akin to this:

```
<form  method="POST" action="{% url 'vote' %}" class="vote_form">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" id="id_link" name="link" class="hidden_id" value="{{ link.pk }}">
<input type="hidden" id="id_voter" name="voter" class="hidden_id" value="{{ user.pk }}">
<input type="hidden" id="id_page" name="section_number" value="{{ forloop.counter }}">  

<input class="voting" type="submit" name="val" value="upvote"><br>
<input class="voting" type="submit" name="val" value="downvote">

</form>
```

The voting **now** happens via simply the following:

```
<a href="{% url 'vote' link.pk user.pk forloop.counter 1 %}">upvote</a><br>
<a href="{% url 'vote' link.pk user.pk forloop.counter 0 %}">downvote</a>
```

My two questions are:

1) All else equal (ceteris paribus), is there any difference in these two methods in terms of **security**? I ran Wapiti (a security scanner) on my website; the latter method popped several security risks (SQL injection, Blind SQL injection, etc) whereas the former method comes out completely clean (but yes, I did change some underlying code as well).

2) The former method left a POST log entry in nginx logs. How would the latter method show up in nginx logs? GET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing *insecure* in your code, but that still doesn't make it a good idea.

Generally you should avoid doing actions that affect the database on a GET. One possible consequence is that if a search engine crawled your site, it would follow the voting links and cause votes to actually be registered; this wouldn't happen with your original code, because search engines don't submit forms.